# Python string opts with unicode, UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, unicode

Suppose if I had a string with some unicode characters inside it, and we needed to do operations on it, what would be the best way to do so?

```
s = u"blah ascii_word etc شاهد word1 word 2" # Delimited by spaces

words = s.split(u' ')

>>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in 
    position 91: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any clues?

Also, If I wanted to write this code into a text file and read it back later, what would be the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare variable the way you do Python assumes it is in your default system encoding you have to add u before the string to make it unicode and add encoding declaration at the top of your file, if you do this you won't get any errors:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = u"blah ascii_word etc شاهد word1 word 2"
words = s.split(u' ')
print words
# no error even tough my default system's encoding is ascii
```

I've checked this now and you don't even need the u - adding encoding is enough to fix the problem.

If you want to do things with unicode strings in the termainal you have to check your system encoding and change it if necessary:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii' #I have ascii
```

You can then manipulate this by using [sys.setdefaultencoding()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding). But this is a tricky issue which depends on your operating system.